# cgi doesn't execute HTML

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to build a python server in order to create a web site running python code as back-end.For that I'm using cgi first (as a test) to display a html page but it doesn't work.

For that I'm using cgi first (as a test) to display a html page but it doesn't work.

here the code of my server :
    import http.server

```
PORT = 8888
server_address = ("", PORT)

server = http.server.HTTPServer
handler = http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
handler.cgi_directories =     ["/Users/mydirectory/Desktop/STAGE_AREMIS_FRANCE/python"]
print("Serveur actif sur le port :", PORT)

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

and here to one of the index :
    # coding: utf-8

```
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n")

print(form.getvalue("name"))

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>Mon programme</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/index.py" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Votre nom" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Envoyer information au serveur">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
"""

print(html)
```

I've read the doc of cgi and I can't figure why it doesn't work.
Any ideas? 
thanks for the help !

Comment: Why are you doing this? Just for learning? I would use a framework like Django, otherwise you will need to reinvent and resolve issues which have been already solved.

Comment: yes I'm doing it to learn but it's seems to my that this way was easier than using Django

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that `cgi_directories` is a list of directories relative to the root of your server directory, but it looks that you are setting a path relative to the root of your file system.

It is by default: `['/cgi-bin', '/htbin']`. I would recommend to just keep the default, create a subdirectory named `cgi-bin` and move your script there.

Comment: Thank's for the answer , I don't know if my question is clear. Once the server activated he recognized the directory find the file but instead of showing the site it shows the code .

Comment: But I tried your way and now I have this error message :

Comment: Error code: 403

Message: CGI script is not a plain file ('/cgi-bin/').

Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN - Request forbidden -- authorization will not help.

Comment: I think you are asking for the directory `/cgi-bin`. Even if your script is called `index` you have to append it to the url.

Comment: You're right when I append index  it create a directory with .DS STORE and a my index.py file but it still display the code instead of the Website

Comment: Maybe you have to mark the file as executable and add a shebang line. Did you try running it manually?

Comment: I did add privileges to the files but still doesn't work. Thanks for your answers ! I'm going to try to do it an other way . I've coded a all programme for data analysis that really work well and I wanted to make it more "user friendly". Something more prettier than Tkinter. I tried to made a python server to have a web interface but it doesn't work .If you have any ideas tell me

Comment: If you are into web programming you could use Django, which is quite nice. If you want to go try a full client, I like pygtk.